# Recursive Insertion Sort in python

Tags: python, sorting

I am trying to write iterative and recursive versions of all the sorting algorithms in python.
Other than the fact that I am not returning anything, what is wrong with this? Is it a problem with my slicing?

Attempt at solution:

```
    def insertOne(element, aList):
    ''' Inserts element into its proper place in a sorted list aList.
        input: element is an item to be inserted.  aList is a sorted list.
        output: A sorted list.
    '''
    if len(aList) == 0:
        return [element]
    elif element < aList[0]:
        return [element] + aList
    else:
        return aList[0:1] + insertOne(element, aList[1:])





    def sort(aList):

    if len(aList) == 0:
        return []

    n = len(aList)
    if n > 1:
        sort(aList[:n - 1])
        insertOne(n, aList)




     aList = [3,2,1]

     print sort(aList)
```

Comment: The first thing wrong would be your indentation. Python uses indentation to determine the bounds of multi-line statements like `if` and `for`; this code will fail on line 1 with an IndentationError.

Comment: The second problem is that you're mixing up in-place operations and things that return new lists. `aList[:n - 1]` is a new, independent list constructed from `aList`; sorting it won't affect `aList` at all. Similarly, returning something from `insertOne` won't affect the value of `aList`.

Comment: The third problem would be that `insertOne` is supposed to take an element to insert and a sorted sublist to insert into, but `insertOne(n, aList)` passes an index and a partially sorted list that already contains the element you want to insert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `sort` method is wrong. `n` is the length of `aList`, not an element. You wouldn't want to put it in the list, which is what you're doing with `insertOne(n, aList)`.

What you want to do is this:

```
def sort(aList):
  if len(aList)<=1:
    return aList
  else:
    return insertOne(aList[0], sort(aList[1:]))
```

Basically, you're going through `aList`, and inserting every element you encounter in its correct position using `insertOne`.